why is C's pow() more precise than cpow()?
When I compile the following code
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <math.h>


double complex testVar;

int main(void) {
    testVar = 10;
    double complex a = 9;
    double complex b = 6;
    double aDouble = 9;
    double bDouble = 6;
    int aInt = 9;
    int bInt = 6;
    printf("Result of cpow() with double complex arguments: %.15f\n", creal(cpow(a, b)));
    printf("Result of cpow() with double arguments: %.15f\n", creal(cpow(aDouble, bDouble)));
    printf("Result of cpow() with int arguments: %.15f\n", creal(cpow(aInt, bInt)));
    printf("Result of cpow() no variables: %.15f\n", creal(cpow(9, 6)));
    printf("Result of pow(): %.15f\n", pow(aDouble, bDouble));
    }

with gcc test_cpow.c -lm -Wall (version 11.4.0 on ubuntu) and I run it I get:
Result of cpow() with double complex arguments: 531441.000000000116415
Result of cpow() with double arguments: 531441.000000000116415
Result of cpow() with int arguments: 531441.000000000116415
Result of cpow() no variables: 531441.000000000000000
Result of pow(): 531441.000000000000000

Is there a bug in cpow()?
I would expect its behavior to have the same precision as pow() if the numbers are real, although they are represented by a double complex type.
Note: this question is not answered by this, because pow() does a better job than cpow()

I suspect this is a bug in the optimizer, since the difference is when you give literal arguments.

With -O0, the 4th call to cpow is optimized away.  With -O1 and higher, all calls to cpow and pow are optimized away.

You are close to the limit of double's precision anyway. If it isn't enough for your purposes, use long double.


pow() may take the time to do integer math when arguments are whole numbers 9 & 6.   531441 is only a 15-bit value.  I would not expect cpow() to test for integer values.  2) 531441.000000000116415 is within 1.0 ULP of 531441.0. cpow() and pow() performing within 1.0 ULP is a reasonable expectation.


@chux-ReinstateMonica minor: 531441 is a 20-bit value.

@weather Yes 20-bit.

This is actually related to glibc, not gcc.
If we look at the glibc code for cpow, specifically at math/s_cpow_template.c, we find the following:
CFLOAT
M_DECL_FUNC (__cpow) (CFLOAT x, CFLOAT c)
{
  return M_SUF (__cexp) (c * M_SUF (__clog) (x));
}

So it looks like cpow is using the "xy = ey ln x" equivalency.
If we do the equivalent operation with real types:
printf("Result of e^(y ln x)(): %.15f\n", exp(bDouble * log(aDouble)));

The result matches what the complex types comes up with:
Result of e^(y ln x)(): 531441.000000000116415

On the other end, if we look at math/w_pow_template.c we see that pow  contains the following code:
M_DECL_FUNC (__pow) (FLOAT x, FLOAT y)
{
  FLOAT z = M_SUF (__ieee754_pow) (x, y);
  /* checks for infinity / nan, removed for brevity */
  return z;
}

Which looks to be calling an intrinsic function.
So the difference between the two is that one uses "xy = ey ln x" to get the result, while the other doesn't.

Basically the answer is - it is as it is. Live with it :)

That makes sense, thanks! When I run the same code on an embedded ARM that uses newlib, the result I get is what I would expect, since that libc uses a different algorithm. So the next question is why doesn't cpow() uses pow() when the numbers are positive real?
